# layer type borders with css3

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a layer type border only with css without using image?
example: http://screensnapr.com/e/WxD1DI.png

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer :

No, you don't ***want*** to do that.

Long answer :

Yes!

First of all,

## Welcome to css hell.

The actual answers :

1st option : Position shape and play with background to do it, [like this awesome Dark Vader](http://kristriplett.com/tinker/vader.html).

2nd option : Use border-width, like in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDxYJ/39/) (that I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698830/curved-lines-using-only-html-and-or-css)).

3rd option : Use Canvas / SVG, which are not supported in old version of IE.