# How to make arc shapes with CSS3?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve following look, with pure css:

[image]

Where each white arc is a different element, say span. I know we can make round shapes with css, but how can it be turned into arc sort of shape?

Comment: Here is a JFiddle that might be of interest http://jsfiddle.net/tupCW/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4699096/684932 ( http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/nDxYJ/ )

Comment: This is all wrong. You should use SVG or Canvas for this.

Comment: @Mircea I have been thinking for an hour or two and I had not thought of SVG at all. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

With the following HTML:

```
<div id="arcs">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#arcs div {
    border: 2px solid #000; /* the 'strokes' of the arc */
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 4em; /* the width of the innermost element */
    min-height: 4em; /* the height of the innermost element */
    padding: 0.5em; /* the spacing between each arc */
    border-radius: 50%; /* for making the elements 'round' */
    border-top-color: transparent; /* hiding the top border */
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```css
#arcs div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  /* the 'strokes' of the arc */
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 4em;
  /* the width of the innermost element */
  min-height: 4em;
  /* the height of the innermost element */
  padding: 0.5em;
  /* the spacing between each arc */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* for making the elements 'round' */
  border-top-color: transparent;
  /* hiding the top border */
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="arcs">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KcmfC/).

Comment: Oh, thank you very much; and I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Comment: @DavidThomas you did a beautiful and creative trick, it makes me feel ;)

Comment: @RaphaelDDL: thanks! I realised, after I saw your edit, that I'd forgotten to add my demo to the answer (despite using it to test the code I posted in my answer...d'oh!), edited to add my own in (finally..!)

Comment: @DavidThomas One more question, I tried achieving this with padding, but it screws things up, Is there any chance to increase space in the middle? (so between left group of arcs and right group?) I guess setting border transparent to left and right will work, but that will require more elements

Comment: Well, I set that space with the `min-width` property (as noted in the code comments), try changing that to a distance/unit that works for you?

Comment: +1 Here's a [version of the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/2wt5V/) with background colors, to make what's happening a little more obvious. And as a curiosity, here's [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/6x4wH/1/) showing how a very different effect is achieved when defining `border-left` and `border-right`, rather than defining `border` and making the top and bottom borders `transparent`.

Comment: Np. It's always good to have a demo :) @Matt I was trying do this code and ended with that different effect you showed, by having this weird gradient rounded border

Comment: @DavidThomas And just to show you how this great trick was applied, check this out! http://musicglaze.com hope you like it ;))) press play on any of the players.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Can you take a look at my question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68222869
I'm trying to make the same shape but in 3D

Comment: The trick here is using the `em` unit, since it will be relative to the parent! and therefore, causing this effect

Answer (score 9):

### SVG Approach:

I would recommend you to use SVG to draw such shapes:

In the example below I've used SVG's `path` element to draw an arc. This element takes single attribute `d` to describe the shape structure. `d` attributes takes a few commands and corresponding necessary parameters.

I've used only 2 path commands:

- `M` command is used to move the pen to a specific point. This command takes 2 parameters `x` and `y` and usually our path begins with this command. It basically defines starting point of our drawing.
- `A` command which is used to draw curves and arcs. This commands takes 7 parameters to draw an arc / curve. A detailed explanation of this command is [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs).

**Screenshot:**

[image: Image Showing arcs]

**Useful Resources:**

- [Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)

**Working Example:**

```css
svg {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <defs>
    <g id="arcs" fill="none" stroke="#fcfcfc">
      <path d="M80,80 A100,100,0, 0,0 80,220" stroke-width="4" />
      <path d="M90,90 A85,85,0, 0,0 90,210" stroke-width="3.5" />
      <path d="M100,100 A70,70,0, 0,0 100,200" stroke-width="3" />
      <path d="M110,110 A55,55,0, 0,0 110,190" stroke-width="2.5" />
    </g>
  </defs>
  
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" fill="#373737" />

  <use xlink:href="#arcs" />
  <use xlink:href="#arcs" transform="translate(300,300) rotate(180)" />
  
</svg>
```

Comment: actually, this is not welcome if you decide to work with border customizations, (in case you want rounded border corners). since you cannot draw a "stroke-width" border