# Line with indented circle

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I would like to know how this heart with the indented circle around it is implemented. How can I make the curves go like this? Is it possible with CSS, HTML?

I know how to implement a heart with CSS or even an image, but the curved border is beyond my knowledge.

`border-radius` doesn't seem to be a solution in this case.

[image: border with indented circle]

Comment: have you tried inspecting the element?

Comment: It seems to be an image. Post URL or check it with Firebug or something like that.

Comment: Sorry but I can't, this is a mockup.

Comment: Check whether it is image or svg? And give border to image or svg.

Comment: Why the -1? Please explain so I can improve my question.

Comment: u should show the research u have lrdy done like how to make a circle and if it is posible to make a heart shape, this stuff can be found by googling. stackoverflow isnt here to make stuff for you that said this is a tricky one :P-

Comment: Maybe OP just want to know best ways to achieve this (I just guess)?

Comment: In this case, using CSS to make this 'shape' would be overly comlex with multiple elements and a great deal of CSS. Use an image or SVG. Frankly, even without code, this question is **too broad** for SO and I'm voting to close accordingly.

Comment: @IvanSanderdeJong I have improved my question a bit, I hope you remove the downvote or help me improve it further.

Comment: the downvote wasn't mine just opvoted it though XD

Comment: @IvanSanderdeJong Thank you. I don't mind downvotes as long as they're accompanied by a comment so I can improve the question.

Comment: @hermann I rolled back to the previous version and added the svg tag. I think if you want to make it less broad, you need to remove the unwanted parts in the image and add a coded attempt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an idea of how you can achieve this layout with an inline svg.

In the SVG :

- The first path is the line with the indented circle. The indented circle is created with an arc command
- The second path element is the heart outline. It uses the Bezier curve command for the top part of the heart.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/200" alt="">
<div>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 18.4">
    <path stroke="orange" stroke-width="0.8" fill="#fff" d="M-1 21 V18 H79.5 A7 7 0 1 1 90.5 18 H101 V21" />
    <path stroke="orange" stroke-width="0.8" fill="#fff" d="M85 18 L81 13 C80 10 85 10 85 12 C85 10 90 10 89 13z " />
  </svg>
</div>
```

*For more info on the path commands in SVG, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)*

Answer (score 7):

You can use a pseudo-element:

```css
$borderWidth: 3px;
$heartSize: 30px;
div {
  border-bottom: $borderWidth solid orange;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  content: '♡'; /* Heart character (U+2661) */
  font-size: 30px;
  height: $heartSize;
  width: $heartSize;
  line-height: $heartSize;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3*$borderWidth;
  right: 10%;
  border: $borderWidth solid orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  clip: rect(0, $heartSize+2*$borderWidth, $heartSize, 0); /* Old syntax */
  clip-path: inset(0 0 2*$borderWidth 0); /* New syntax */
}
```

```css
div {
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  content: '♡'; /* Heart character (U+2661) */
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9px;
  right: 15%;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  clip: rect(0, 36px, 30px, 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 6px 0); /* Old syntax */
  clip-path: inset(0 0 6px 0); /* New syntax */
}
```

```html
<div>Foo<br />bar</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

So the best solution for your problem would be to use an SVG shape [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/993uj2uh/), or a custom font as you can modify the colour and they will scale well for retina etc.

Normally CSS3 is great for creating basic shapes, however when it comes to outline shapes it kind off falls over. This is because they normally rely on creating multiple shapes using before and after selectors. This normally works but if you want to apply a border it will cause overlapping issues with the shape.

The only real css solution would be to create a second heart shape slightly smaller as a mask. But this is allot of markup bloat so SVG really is your best option.

A quick and dirty example over and overlapping heart is here https://jsfiddle.net/6qywoxsk/

```css
.heart {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
}
.heartCon{
    position:relative;
}
.heart:before,
.heart:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
         -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
            transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.heart:after {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
         -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
            transform-origin :100% 100%;
}
.heart2{
     -ms-transform: scale(0.9); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9); /* Safari */
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
.heart2:before,
.heart2:after {
     background:#fff;   
     top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heartCon">
  <div class="heart"></div>
  <div class="heart heart2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest, safest and cross-browser solution is to use an image.

The other ways: canvas, border-radius, transform or SVG.

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** want to do it with css, you can try out some image-to-css webservices (like http://image2css.alexdoesit.com/ - just the first to pop up in google)

Although, the simplest and cleanest way is to do it with a transparent image.

As for implementing an arc in CSS3, this answer may help: [How to make arc shapes with CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470412/how-to-make-arc-shapes-with-css3)

Answer (score 1):

### CSS = `border-radius` + `overflow:hidden;`

1. Place the circle as a pseudo-element in the block with `overflow:hidden;`. So we get an arc.
2. Take the heart [from the Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icon/heart-o/). To set the icon by the CSS, create another block with a pseudo-element. If the heart did not protrude beyond the lower boundary of the arc, then it would not be threatened by the `overflow:hidden;` and we would place both pseudo-elements in one block.
3. Position the assembled block on top of the picture with the bottom orange border. Set the negative `bottom` property to lower the block to the depth of the border.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/MoyXxp

```css
.arch {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
.arch:before {
  background: white;
  border: solid 3px orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 133.333333%;
}

.heart {
  position: absolute; bottom: -3px; right: 60px;
  width: 48px; height: 36px;
}
.heart:after {
  color: orange;
  content: '\f08a'; /* http://fontawesome.io/icon/heart-o/ */
  display: block;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute; bottom: -4px; left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.photo {
  background: #9cf;
  border-bottom: solid 3px orange;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo"><div class="heart"><div class="arch"></div></div></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve round shapes with CSS using the `border-radius` property:

```
element {
border-radius: 999px;
border: 5px solid #000; // thick border
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, answered this question prematurely. In case you don't want to solve this using an image, I could think of a workaround.

The lower orange border could be a `<div>` with a height of `1px` or `2px` and a width of `100%`. The heart element could be another div, styled like I explained above. Next, you would just have to apply a higher `z-index` (along with `position: relative`) to the heart, than to the `<div>`. And the you'd need to apply some negative `margin-top` to the `<div>` until it overlaps.

Just an idea, maybe it gets you somewhere.

Comment: Yes, but please explain this this answers the OP's actual question.

Comment: I know this already, but it doesn't help with my question. I cannot reproduce the same effect as the image just with border-radius.