# Arc border in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to make an arc in the right border of a div/panel , please let me know if there are any ways to do it. attached is the snapshot of mockup.[image]

Comment: It'll depend heavily on the rest of the page layout how you accomplish this.

Comment: You can't bend edges with css (you can only make corners rounded). You need SVG, a partially transparent background image or canvas to achieve that.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470412/how-to-make-arc-shapes-with-css3

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi i didn't asked you to write code for me, please read my question completely, i have clearly asked for the ways to implement, if you see my previous post i have provided proper examples and the code i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this effect in CSS. Example below.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap::before {
  content:'';
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -300px;
  margin-left:-280px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.wrap::after {
  content:'';
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -280px;
  margin-left:-290px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
</div>
```