# Draw a curve with css

Tags: css, curve

I want to create an animation with css that simulate a wave movement.
I need to change a line-or div- to a curve for this...
The CSS rules that I'm familiar to, make the entire div to semicircular or change element border.
For example:
`border-radius`, or `perspective` or `border-top-radius`...
This image show you what I want:
[image: curve]

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curved lines using only HTML and/or CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698830/curved-lines-using-only-html-and-or-css)

Comment: Thanks @JoshC, is there any rule that make a irregular curve?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You could use an asymmetrical border to make curves with CSS.

`border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;`

[VIEW DEMO](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/PwWjLL)

```css
.box {
  width: 500px; 
  height: 100px;  
  border: solid 5px #000;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: What if I need that curve to be inside?

Comment: What do you mean by inside? @Navaneeth

Comment: Means a curve with curvature inside. Let's say we have points with y coordinate 10, the curve should be below ten...

Comment: This worked for me: transform: rotateX(180deg);

http://codepen.io/afisher88/pen/vKxvXp

Answer (score 17):

@Navaneeth and @Antfish, no need to transform you can do like this also because in above solution only top border is visible so for inside curve you can use bottom border.

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
  border-radius: 0 0 240px 50%/60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```