# How to draw different shapes using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw the image attached below using HTML and CSS but I am not able to get my expected output.

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
        #center_cir {
            border-left: 48px solid transparent;
            border-right: 50px solid transparent;
            height: 0;
            width: 100px;
            border-top: 100px solid red;
            border-top-left-radius:60px;
            border-top-right-radius:60px;
        }
        #circle {
            width: 140px;
            height: 120px;
            background: red;
            -moz-border-radius: 60px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
            border-radius: 60px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="center_cir">
        <!--<div id="circle">
        </div>-->
    </div>

</html>
```

Comment: what you actually want to create?which shape ?

Comment: [Check this out](https://coveloping.com/tools/css-shapes-generator), there a probably plenty more sites that generate CSS shapes if you do a search

Comment: in bottom border i want curve shape

Comment: Where is image attached?

Comment: here's the similar question answered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803489/draw-a-curve-with-css

Comment: I formatted the code and fixed some typos for better readability. Please attach the image you are mentioning about.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for you... Adjust the color and size and you're done.

```css
#center_cir {
     border-left: 48px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius:60px;
    border-top-right-radius:60px;
  position: relative;

}
#center_cir:after {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
    content: "";
    height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center_cir"></div>
```

Comment: tat bottom curve should be in reverse direction like this (

Comment: it should look like separate circle ... that red color bottom border itself curved inside

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking