# make a css border with an indent at center

Tags: css

I have an image that I place like a top border

[image]

But I was wondering if this could be done with css. For the diamond I could use a `::before` with this:

```
.diamond
{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #b29464;
}
```

but I don't know how to make the indent part. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here are two links worth reading that should get you closer to a solution.
https://codepen.io/robinllopis/pen/PaxgXO 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803489/draw-a-curve-with-css

Comment: I always want to remind people that CSS is not a drawing language or program and using it for things such as this are more of a hack.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can try making it up with 3 parts. 2 lines is visible edges of 2 rectangle  with radius corner on right and left. The left part is your diamond in between. Hope it helps!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  border-top: 2px solid #b29464;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
}
.line2 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  border-top: 2px solid #b29464;
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.diamond
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #b29464;
    margin: 0 -5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Square CSS</h2>
<div class="line1"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="diamond"></div>
</div>
<div class="line2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing a similar concept to the previous answer (and the other web links), but with position absolute for the lines. This style holds its shape on smaller screens.

```
<div class="frame">
<div class="line1"></div>
<div class="line2"></div>
<div class="whitebox"></div>
</div>

div.frame {position: fixed;}
div.line1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 109px;
  border-top: 2px solid #b29464;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
div.line2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-top: 2px solid #b29464;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}
div.whitebox {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #b29464;
  rotate: 45deg;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 99px;
}
```