# Creating a curved div using only CSS

Tags: css

Is there any way to create a *div* that's warped, bent, curved, transformed, etc. to look like the following image? The only thing I've been able to find is manipulating a single border using border-radius, but what I really need is to transform an actual div element with only CSS.

(**Edit:** As comments have pointed out: Yes there are *tons* of solutions that use borders, draw to the canvas, etc. But this question is specifically about manipulating a *div* element using *CSS*)

[image]

[The unanswered Reddit thread where I got the image from.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2ewjqn/is_it_possible_to_create_curved_divs_using_only/)

Comment: do you have any code you tried to share before being downvoted or closed ?

Comment: A general answer to this question would be great as a reference for anyone to use. But just to tack on as a bonus: I'm specifically trying to create a thick, curved line with rounded corners (so imagine the div from the image with rounded corners). Can't find a good solution that isn't hacky and unscalable ):

Comment: @GCyrillus The Reddit thread? It's not actually mine, just a thread I found with the same question I have.

Comment: I don't see why this would be closed... Pretty well explained despite no code... I don't think code would be helpful if @mintychai never even go close to anything...

Comment: best thing you can do before posting a question is to **try** to solve it yourself, in other words: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and **then** ask the question

Comment: @AGE I definitely have extensively tried to find a way to do this. There are actually no resources I can find that solve this problem. I know it seems like this is a simple issue and someone somewhere should have solved it, but as far as I've searched and searched, no one's answered it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curved lines using only HTML and/or CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698830/curved-lines-using-only-html-and-or-css)

Comment: @TylerH I understand curved lines are easy to do, but this question is specifically about manipulating the entire div.

Comment: @mintychai Yes, you would apply this process to the entire div

Comment: @mintychai To be frank, the answer to your question is: you should do this with SVG elements. Everything else will be an approximation/hack.

Comment: @mintychai I was about so say the same as TylerH, CSS could allow for such behavior but SVG would be the right way to go.

Comment: @TylerH I addressed that exact solution in my original question. The issue with a single curved border is that it's functionally different than an actual div-- you can't put content in it nor add additional styling. Still looking for CSS solution but I will look into SVG, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across [an interesting article in CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/). I don't think there's a way to do what you want with a complex div, but if you just wanted banner text. This is **not** a perfect answer, but I think it's the closest you might get. It's really just an illusion of a manipulated div, not the actual thing.

But anyway... I managed to tweak their code a bit like this:

```css
.badge {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
}

h1 span {
background-color: lightblue;
  font: 26px Monaco, MonoSpace;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: center 190px;
}

.char1 {
  transform: rotate(6deg);
}

.char2 {
  transform: rotate(12deg);
}

.char3 {
  transform: rotate(18deg);
}

.char4 {
  transform: rotate(24deg);
}

.char5 {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.char6 {
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}

.char7 {
  transform: rotate(42deg);
}

.char8 {
  transform: rotate(48deg);
}

.char9 {
  transform: rotate(54deg);
}

.char10 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.char11 {
  transform: rotate(66deg);
}

.char12 {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}

.char13 {
  transform: rotate(78deg);
}

.char14 {
  transform: rotate(84deg);
}

.char15 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.char16 {
  transform: rotate(96deg);
}

.char17 {
  transform: rotate(102deg);
}

.char18 {
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}

.char19 {
  transform: rotate(114deg);
}

.char20 {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.char21 {
  transform: rotate(126deg);
}

.char22 {
  transform: rotate(132deg);
}

.char23 {
  transform: rotate(138deg);
}

.char24 {
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="page-wrap">
  
  <div class="badge">
    <h1>
        <span class="char1">E</span>
        <span class="char2">s</span>
        <span class="char3">t</span>
        <span class="char4">a</span>
        <span class="char5">b</span>
        <span class="char6">l</span>
        <span class="char7">i</span>
        <span class="char8">s</span>
        <span class="char9">h</span>
        <span class="char10">e</span>
        <span class="char11">d</span>
        <span class="char12"> </span>
        <span class="char13">2</span>
        <span class="char14">0</span>
        <span class="char15">1</span>
        <span class="char16">2</span>
      </h1>
  </div>
 
 </div>
```

You have to split up the word into separate letter `<span>` elements with specific class names. This is tedious but the article gives some javascript to simplify the breaking up of the word but you said only CSS, so...

As others have said in the comments (though it's not what you're asking for). SVG will likely accomplish this much better.

Comment: Thanks! Especially for actually answering the question-- that "no," it's probably impossible to do what's asked in the question. This is definitely an interesting trick though and I'm messing around with it to get the geometry to all work out for what I'm doing.

For anyone that stumbles across this: you'll basically have to create wrappers and transform the content you want inside the div so that it APPEARS to be curved in the div.

Comment: Exactly playing with the `transform-origin` you can get some interesting results.

Answer (score 4):

```css
.ribbon{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid #d69688;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='ribbon'></div>
```