# Costum curved border with points css

Tags: css, border

Tell me please how can I do something like this in CSS?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXk3z.png)

Comment: SVG or images perhaps... what have you tried?

Comment: try `border-radius` and `position:absolute` read more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698830/curved-lines-using-only-html-and-or-css  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803489/draw-a-curve-with-css and also google search html5 canvas curved line and css3 curved line